TypeError: Cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers of type DataFrame
I'm new with python so I'm sorry if this is a basic one. However, after I ran the code, I got this:
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [   Year  Average of PM Concentration (µg/Ncm)  Annual Guidline Value{µg/Ncm)
0  2012                                  51.0                             60
1  2013                                  49.0                             60
2  2014                                  27.0                             60
3  2015                                  45.5                             60
4  2016                                  59.0                             60
5  2017                                  62.0                             60
6  2018                                  62.0                             60
7  2019                                  57.0                             60] of type DataFrame

This is the code:
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataset from the Downloads folder
data = pd.read_csv('Group2Data.csv')

# Display the first 8 rows of the dataset
print(data.head(8))

I really don't know what went wrong. Can anyone help me please?

Make sure that the column names specified in the error message match the actual column names in your CSV file. If they don't match, you'll need to adjust your code accordingly to use the correct column names.

Can you provide a link to the csv file? Or else paste a few lines of it here as raw text?
